# is out-of-order execution a common concern for concurrent threads in a .Net Core app?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I have read about creating memory barriers as full fence barriers for preventing out-of-order execution.

There is a good resource about this topic here:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

I am now trying to understand how common a concern this is when developing a program that makes use of concurrent threads. It is claimed that the JIT Compiler can reorder instructions, and that the processor can as well. But not all processors can do this so in that case how common is it for the JIT compiler to do this? Does it only do this based on the processor?

I have also read that the spectre vulnerability from 2018 was related to out-of-order execution which makes it seem like it is a very common thing for CPUs to support.

Comment: spectre was primarily branch-prediction, not out-of-order, no? but: most modern *computer* CPUs will do both; less common on lower power CPUs for mobile/IoT, etc

Comment: what the JIT compiler does is at least two layers of abstraction above the kind of reordering discussed here, and of a different kind - a pre-execution reordering as an optimization, still static from the processor's point of view.